# How to get all component's names in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxt3

My project has several levels of component folders:
`

```
/components
   /foo
      File.vue
      File2.vue
         /fooTwo
              Anotherfile.vue
   /bar
      File1.vue
      File10.vue
```

`

This is what i wanted:
`['FooFile','FooFile2','FooFooTwoAnotherfile','BarFile1','BarFile10']`

Answer (score 0):

`.nuxt/components.d.ts` contains a list of all auto-imported components, specifically check those imported form the `components` directory.

More information on auto-import and the .nuxt directory structure:

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/nuxt